# Special character in txt file not being passed in the InputStream

Tags: java

I have an

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/createUser/new-user.txt");
```

and the content of the `new-user.txt` is :

Hello™ how r u    ®

but when they are displayed in the output they are displayed as

Hello��� how r u��

Can you tell me what changes should I make to my txt file so that it starts displaying the data accordingly.

**UPDATE**

So here is the code :-

`Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
InputStream txtInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("templates/createUser/new-user.txt");
Template textTemplate = handlebars.compileInline(IOUtils.toString(txtInputStream));
String emailText = textTemplate.apply(vars);`

Comment: Displayed _where_? This is very important.

Comment: The content is being passed into MailService. Till the time the inputStream is being  passed into the MailService it is looking like ™ but once i see the output mail it becomes ���

Comment: Again, define _see_. This is an encoding problem so whatever tool or tricks you're using to _see_ or _read_ it may have an incorrect encoding. Also, what is the encoding of the file itself?

Comment: ™ is unicode `\u2122`, UTF-8 `E2 84 A2`, and ® is unicode `\u00AE`, UTF-8 `C2 AE`, so the number of `�` would indicate that your file is UTF-8, so make sure you read it as such. You didn't specify how the `InputStream` becomes a `String`, so it's difficult to say where you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie in the InputStream object. InputStreams are just streams of bytes, they do not differentiate between encodings. The problem is you should use this as your reader:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

as opposed to using this:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); // does not specify encoding
```

You can then get the string with:

```
String theString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

**Edit:**
I did not realize you posted full code in the comments. Just change your second to last line to:

```
Template textTemplate = handlebars.compileInline(IOUtils.toString(txtInputStream, "UTF-8"));
```